# Understanding "Buffer Security Check /GS" compiler option in MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was recently surprised to note that compiling with `/GS` (Enable buffer security check) in MSVC++ 2010 seems to have a non-negligible effect on run-time performance in some cases. Has anyone else had this experience??

For a large scientific-style application (a mesh generation library) it seems that compiling with `/GS-` can lead to almost 10% improvements in run-time for several of the large benchmarks in my test suite ("large" being >= 1 second worth of run-time). `/GS` is on by default at all levels of optimisation in MSVC++ 2010.

I must admit that I'd never paid too much attention to this option before, and I'm wanting a bit of clarification as to what it actually does. The online [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110905075657/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa290051) seems to talk extensively about string buffers, but since I don't use `string` or `char[]` buffers anywhere I must be missing something.

This paragraph (from the online doc) seems to indicate that the performance degradation I'm seeing is a bit unusual:

> A performance tradeoff for using
> security checks in an application must
> be made. The Visual C++ compiler team
> focused on making the performance
> degradation small. In most cases, the
> performance should not degrade more
> than 2 percent. In fact, experience
> has shown that most applications,
> including high-performance server
> applications, have not noticed any
> performance impact.

Of course I can just turn it off, and get faster code, but I want to understand the implications before I do that.

Comment: There's lots of code, including "high-performance server applications", which is I/O bound or memory bound. Inserting extra checks is practically free in such code.

Comment: Michael Howard has an article that mentions some of the things added to /GS support since Bray's 2002 article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337897.aspx

Comment: The URL in Michael Burr's comment now redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/march/security-briefs-protecting-your-code-with-visual-c-defenses

Answer (score 14, accepted):

/GS adds code that tries to detect if a write overrun or similar stack attack has happend during a function, and to stop execution after a write overrun. The patterns that it aims to find are ones that have been seen in real-world attacks. There are a bunch of real world security bulletins that would not have happened if today's /GS had been in use at the time.

In this case a write overrun can happen on structures, arrays and various other entities. Changes and improvements to /GS are made in each version of VS. More /GS protection generally has cost, although in some cases newer VS may have learnt how to do the same protection cheaper.

I'd recommend leaving /GS on unless your code doesn't ship to others - generally the protection is worth the cost; at most you might choose to disable it for specific functions where there is no risk and high impact - just as you might hand-optimise the most critical parts of your program in other ways.

Martyn

Comment: So are you saying that these checks are/can be done on all stack-based buffers with `/GS` on?? I'm a bit confused by the online doc talking mostly about `char[]` buffers.

Comment: These checks are applied to a wide variety of types, depending on the cost/benefit of the checks. Heuristics are applied, which are updated over time. The docs talk about char because that is the most familiar kind of BO, but in fact real security problems have been caused by other overflows.

Comment: Does the /GS option is designed/aimed at finding buffer overruns which are bugs, i.e the programmer's fault, or is the security against attacks the only issue?

Comment: /GS just helps find overruns. It was targeted to reduce security issues, but it will just as happily find overruns that may not have security implications.

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same experience as you: /GS- leading to ~10% improvements in runtime. I've shared some benchmarks on my blog: [The Cost of Buffer Security Checks in Visual C++](http://preshing.com/20110807/the-cost-of-buffer-security-checks-in-visual-c)

When /GS is enabled (which is the default for the VC++ Release configuration), it seems anytime you create a C-style array as a local variable, the compiler will insert a few extra instructions to ensure the 4 bytes following the array on the stack have not been modified. As you've noticed, it doesn't seem to matter if it's a char array, or an array of another type. I guess the idea behind this compiler option is that any stack buffer overflow could be exploited by hackers, regardless of type.

But if you’re developing a Visual C++ application which is not a network service, and you’re striving for maximum performance, such as in a game, editor, or benchmarking tool — and it’s unlikely to be targeted by hackers — then I'd suggest to go ahead and disable this option.

Answer (score 1):

TrendMicro will flag your application as suspicious for compiling with /GS- for performance.

TrendMicro-HouseCall  Suspicious_GEN.F47V0828.

It seems they also ignore all requests to re-evaluate as false positive.